# Different css for table if table has only one row

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have multiple tables on a website. In case the table has multiple rows, then each cell should be bordered which is solved now with `td {border: 1px solid black;}`. But if the table only has one single row, I would like to hide the borders or have the border-width be 0.

Without changing the HTML or using JS, is there a way to accomplish this purely with CSS?

Comment: I dont see a way without JS or hardcoding it in HTMl by adding a class. How should the document know that a table only has 1 row and shoul apply a different style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a selector for a single row.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table tbody tr:only-child td { /* The override. */
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>5</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```